# PowerPoint add-in "RichApi.Error: Slide does not have a SlideMaster." error

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js

I am working on an add-in and after looking into the logs I discovered that some users are getting RichApi.Error: Slide does not have a SlideMaster. error. I am inserting the slide from the base64 and then reading the slide's SlideMaster:

```js
PowerPoint.run(async context => {
  context.presentation.insertSlidesFromBase64(base64Slide)
  await context.sync()

  const slide = context.presentation.slides.getItemAt(0).load(['id', 'shapes'])
  await context.sync()
  const slideMaster = slide.slideMaster.load(['id', 'layouts'])
  await context.sync()
})
```

This line is throwing the exception:

> const slideMaster = slide.slideMaster.load(['id', 'layouts'])

I am trying to reproduce but no success and everything is working fine for me.